# is Ionic 4 secure storage encryption actually secure?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, encryption, ionic4

I'm building an app that requires a user to go near a GPS location. Right now i'm getting their location every 30 seconds, sending it to my server, verifying if they are near it and then returning the answer. The issue is they might not have service and it's making 2 calls every minute for every user.

I was looking into using Ionic Secure Storage

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/secure-storage

I would download the gps coordinates and then just match it locally instead of sending a server call however I'm worried that secure storage isn't actually that secure. I need 100% to make sure the user cannot get access to the GPS coordinates. Is the only true way to do this via server communication or is secure storage actually secure enough for this? Or is there a way I can encrypt the gps coordinates before sending them and then verifying locally without the user being able to see them?

Comment: Just hash the coordinates, rounded to some acceptable precision, and compare the hashes. There may also be specialized hash functions for spatial coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, You are fetching values from GPS and matching them with your locally stored values. And you are worried about security of secure-storage.

> 1.Secure-Storage uses your browser storage, So one will only get access to browser storage unless and until he gets the physical access to device.
>
> 2.Secure-Storage uses your browser storage and it is only accessible through the key. So it is not accessible to normal person even if browser data is captured.
>
> 3.If both cases failed for you, Use JWT Token or something like that to encrypt your local data and can be only accessible through JWT key. So that If anyone gets your local data he cannot able to read that.

You can refer [this](https://devdactic.com/jwt-authentication-ionic/) for implementing JWT token.